# Can I use the result of a previous MySQL query in the From section of another MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a PHP webservice where I have performed a simple SELECT query, and stored it

```
$result = run_query($get_query);
```

I now need to perform further querying on the data based on different parameters, which I know is possible via MySQL in the form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM customers
      WHERE CompanyName > 'g')
WHERE ContactName < 'g'
```

I do know that this performs two Select queries on the table. However, what I would like to know is if I can simply use my previously saved query in the FROM section of the second section, such as this, and if my belief that it helps performance by not querying the entire database again is true:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ($result)
WHERE ContactName < 'g'
```

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350279/mysql-php-query-a-result-set

Comment: @codea it's not a duplicate.. This is a performance question not a simple "how to query a result set"

Comment: I admit there's a difference here

Answer (score 1):

You can make a temp table to put the initial results and then use it to select the data and in the second query. This will work faster only if your 1-st query is slow.

Comment: The issue with this would, in my opinion, have been if there were several users concurrently accessing the webservice, which I have to believe would be yes.

Comment: Temp tables are only visible for the session that created them.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Will try it out to see how it compares to the function I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP and SQL are different languages and very different platforms. They often don't even run in the same computer. Your PHP variables won't interact at all with the MySQL server. You use PHP to create a string that happens to contain SQL code but that's all. In the end, the only thing that counts is the SQL code you sent to the server—how you manage to generate it is irrelevant.

Additionally, you can't really say how MySQL will run a query unless you obtain an explain plan:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM customers
      WHERE CompanyName > 'g')
WHERE ContactName < 'g'
```

... but I doubt it'll read the table twice for your query. Memory is much faster than disk.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses, everyone. Turns out what I was looking for was a "query of query", which isn't supported directly by PHP but I found a function over here which provides the functionality: http://www.tom-muck.com/blog/index.cfm?newsid=37

That was found from this other SO question: [Can php query the results from a previous query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798421/can-php-query-the-results-from-a-previous-query?rq=1)

I still need to do comparisons to determine whether it improves speed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know whether saving the "from" part of your SQL query in a php variable improves the performance of you querying your SQL server, then the answer is NO. Simply because the variable keeping the value is inserted into the query.

Whether performance is gained in PHP, the answer is most probable yes; but depends on the length of the variable value (and how often you repeat using the variable instead of building a new complete query) whether the performance will be notable.

Comment: I'm not saving the Where part in $result, but the result from running the first Query. The second statement then queries the result of the first one, which I believe should help by not requiring the PHP file to access the entire MySQL table again and instead deal only with the stored result.

Comment: Then it's foolish to store the results from your first query. It would be wiser to combine both queries into one longer one. That is always better as in performance.

Comment: I need to perform three different variations of the third query. The table itself soon becomes exceedingly large, so I'd like to minimize the number of times I query it, which is why I wanted to use the result of the first query instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Then ofcourse your method is smart. Query once to reduce overhead of additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get this data in a single query like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
WHERE CompanyName > 'g'
AND ContactName < 'g'
```

Comment: I believe the question is about performance not about how to query the database nor how to succesfully combine queries, even though it would make sense to advice to improve the sql performance at its roots.

Comment: @Luceos Yes I understand that.  This query would give best performance as it would allow indexes on CompanyName and ContactName to be used using subselect will disallow use of index for the ContactName query.

Comment: This was meant to be an example, and that isn't exactly the query being performed. There are 3 of the second queries, so by doing the above, instead of accessing the MySQL table 3 times separately, I'd be doing so only once, and then dealing with the stored result the number of times I need to.

Comment: @RaveeshBhalla OK.  You would still probably have better query performance querying the database 3 times like I have shown than once with an initial query and then 3 additional time utilizing an initial query results set (if such was even possible). If you have some intermediate result set you then need to query against, you best best might be to put this data into a memory table and then query against that table. You should of course run your own performance testing to see what works best for you.

Comment: I've added an answer as I found out what I'm looking for is a query of query. It's not supported by PHP, but there's a function available for it. I still need to determine if it improves performance, however.